# [Vue warn]: Error in directive sortable update hook: "Sortable: el must be HTMLElement, and not [object Undefined]"

Tags: vue.js

In my vue.js project, I follow the GitHub steps to use `vue-sortable`:

```
import Sortable from 'vue-sortable'
Vue.use(Sortable)

    <div id="frame_layout"  v-sortable>

        <div>
            one
        </div>

        <div>
            two
        </div>
        <div>
            three
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I will get bellow error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in directive sortable update hook: "Sortable: el must be HTMLElement, and not [object Undefined]"

Comment: which version of `vue.js` are you using?

Comment: I use `vue 2.0`

Answer (score 3):

The [vue-sortable](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-sortable) do not support Vue.js 2.0 now. From the GitHub you can see the last update is two years ago.

You can use [Vue-Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable)  for replace.

Comment: Good call, their package.json show `"vue": "^1.0.26"`. +1